# How can I change CSS animations with a variable given from typescript

Tags: css, typescript, animation

I have a lot of individual animations for different elements which all do the same just with a different color.
In my .ts file I have a variable this.fillColor which contains the RGB value of the clicked element.
Is there a way how I can shorten the animations to 1 block of code and change the hardcoded RGB value to that variable?

```
#loading {
    animation-name:             changing;
    animation-duration:         4s;
    animation-direction:        alternate;
    animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  }

  @keyframes changing {
      0% {
          fill:rgb(105,105,105);
          width: 20px;
      }
      100% {
          fill: rgb(250,230,0);
          width: 200px;
      }
  }

  #loading2 {
    animation-name:             changing2;
    animation-duration:         4s;
    animation-direction:        alternate;
    animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  }

  @keyframes changing2 {
      0% {
          fill:rgb(105,105,105);
          width: 20px;
      }
      100% {
          fill: rgb(13,255,191);
          width: 200px;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use CSS variables/custom properties to do that for you. The second argument in `var()` accepts a fallback/default value, in case the CSS variable is undefined.

For example, if you wan to set `#loading` start and end fill colors to a custom value, you can do this:

```
@keyframes changing {
    0% {
        fill: var(--loading-fill-from, rgb(105,105,105));
        width: 20px;
    }
    100% {
        fill: var(--loading-fill-to, rgb(250,230,0));
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

This means that the `changing` keyframe will have the *default* fallback colors of `rgb(105, 105, 105)` for the start and `rgb(250, 230, 0)` for the end, but also accepts `--loading-fill-from` and `--loading-fill-to` custom properties if specified.

You can set these on the root element, since CSS custom properties are inheritable:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--loading-fill-from', YOUR_COLOR_HERE);
```

---

Here is a proof-of-concept example below (written in ES6 JS, but you can easily just convert it to TypeScript yourself):

```js
const varNames = ['loading-fill-from', 'loading-fill-to', 'loading2-fill-from', 'loading2-fill-to'];
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let varName of varNames) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${varName}`, document.querySelector(`#${varName}`).value);
  }
});
```

```css
#loading {
    animation-name:             changing;
    animation-duration:         4s;
    animation-direction:        alternate;
    animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  }

  @keyframes changing {
      0% {
          fill: var(--loading-fill-from, rgb(105,105,105));
          width: 20px;
      }
      100% {
          fill: var(--loading-fill-to, rgb(250,230,0));
          width: 200px;
      }
  }

  #loading2 {
    animation-name:             changing2;
    animation-duration:         4s;
    animation-direction:        alternate;
    animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  }

  @keyframes changing2 {
      0% {
          fill: var(---loading2-fill-from, rgb(105,105,105));
          width: 20px;
      }
      100% {
          fill: var(--loading2-fill-to, rgb(13,255,191));
          width: 200px;
      }
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>#loading</legend>
    <label>
      Loading button fill from:
      <input type="color" id="loading-fill-from" value="#005f73"/>
    </label>
    <label>
      Loading button fill to:
      <input type="color" id="loading-fill-to" value="#94d2bd" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>#loading2</legend>
    <label>
      Loading2 button fill from:
      <input type="color" id="loading2-fill-from" value="#f07167" />
    </label>
    <label>
      Loading2 button fill to:
      <input type="color" id="loading2-fill-to" value="#fed9b7" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button" id="btn">Change color</button>
</form>

<svg id="loading" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" /></svg>

<svg id="loading2" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" /></svg>
```